# Dúvida sobre <button></button>

Tags: php, javascript

Estou fazendo um sistema de comentários, na forma de lista. Em cada uma das linhas da lista há um botão do tipo `<button>`, cada um com um nome diferente.

E a minha dúvida é como fazer a seguinte sintaxe de *if-else* em PHP:

```
If (o "< button >< /button >" de nome $idcomentario for clicado){***

    $comando = $PDO->prepare("DELETE comentario FROM comentarios WHERE 
    idcomentario = :idcomentario");

    $comando->bindValue(':idcomentario', $idcomentario);
    $comando->execute();    

}else{
    //nada acontece...
}
```

Ou seja, quando se clica no botão, o comentário cujo "id" corresponde ao nome do botão é deletado do banco.

Se não der para fazer em PHP, como ficaria em JavaScript? Lembrando que eu teria que realizar uma operação em BD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da forma que você quer fazer eu não considero uma boa prática, você não deve executar a funcionalidade na *view*, isso é responsabilidade do *controller.*
Então você pode fazer da seguinte maneira, no seu loop de exibição de comentários você vai colocar alguma informação única para identificar o comentário.

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ( $comments as $comment ) ?>
    <li>
       <button class="btn-remove" data-id="<?php echo $comment->id ?>">Excluir</button>  // Esse data-id será o campo do qual vamos pegar o ID do comentário
    <li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Depois você vai criar um **ajax** para ser executado no momento de *click* desse botão.

```
$('.btn-remove').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: url, // URL da rota onde você vai executar no PHP
        data: { comment_id: id },
        datatype: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            // Aqui você vai tratar o retorno da sua função em PHP
        }
    });
});
```

No seu arquivo **PHP** você vai criar a função para remover o comentário selecionado.

```
// Antes de remover o comentário aconselho você fazer algumas validações
// Como por exemplo se o comentário já foi removido e etc.
function removeComment( $id ) {
    $comando = $PDO->prepare("DELETE comentario FROM comentarios WHERE idcomentario = :idcomentario");

    $comando->bindValue(':idcomentario', $id);
    $comando->execute();   

    return true; // Dependendo da sua validação retorne *true* ou *false* 
}
```

<sub>Os exemplos acima são apenas para ilustrar a forma que você deve fazer, por isso copiar e colar o código não resolverá o seu problema.</sub>

Comment: Testei no navegador e deu que o $ do $('.btn-remove') não está definido...

Comment: Amigo, o que seria esse comment_id???

Comment: O comment_id é a chave primária da entidade comentários na sua base de dados. Sobre o comentário anterior, eu falei sobre não apenas copiar e colar o código, os exemplos servem apenas para você se basear na ideia e não copiar e colar para funcionar.

Comment: Ok, na verdade o erro no cifrão era porque não tinha importado a biblioteca jquery